# How to use xpath within this class data-v-056fbda class

Tags: html, xpath

I am trying to make a scrapy spider to get the price from this web page but the regular expressions doesnt seem to work for xpath.

I'd like to xpath the price-integer and price-decimal combined. How can I do that with xpath an css?

Thanks.

HTML:

```
<div data-binded="true" class="vue-price-box">
<div class="PriceBoxWrapper">
    <div data-v-7116dae8="" class="PriceBoxW">
        <div data-v-7116dae8="" class="PriceBoxW-offer">
            <span data-v-7116dae8="" class="PriceBoxW-listPrice">
            <span data-v-0656fbda="" data-v-7116dae8="" class="Price">
                    <span data-v-0656fbda="" class="Price-currency">R$</span> 
                    <span data-v-0656fbda="" class="Price-integer">89</span> 
                    <span data-v-0656fbda="" class="Price-decimal">,90</span></span> 
                <span data-v-b5abd2a4="" data-v-7116dae8="" class="DiscountTag" style="background-color: rgb(246, 139, 44);">
                <span data-v-b5abd2a4="" class="caption">31% OFF</span></span></span> <span data-v-7116dae8="" class="PriceBoxW-member">
                <span data-v-7116dae8="" class="PriceBoxW-member-title caption">Sócio <br data-v-7116dae8="">Wine</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

2 options with two single XPath expressions :

```
translate(substring(normalize-space(//span[@class="Price"]),4)," ","")

concat(//span[@class="Price-integer"],//span[@class="Price-decimal"])
```

Output :

```
89,90
```

In the first expression, we get all the texts descendant from a specific span element in one string. We slice it and remove the useless whitespace. In the second expression, we concat the content from the 2 text nodes which contain the product price.

1 solution with `Python` and `LXML` :

```
import lxml.html
tree = lxml.html.fromstring(data)
print("".join(els.text for els in tree.xpath('//span[@class="Price"]/span[position()>1]')))
```

where `data` is your sample HTML. We use `.text` to get the content of the nodes then `join` to merge the results of the XPath expression.

Output :

```
89,90
```